# Content DB log files growing out of control when using Lists.asmx to update three fields on a library

Tags: 2007, wss-3.0, web-services, migration, sharepoint-foundation

I've created a console application to migrate files from legacy SharePoint servers to a new server utilizing SharePoint Foundation 2010. I'm using Lists.asmx to get list information and update three fields on the source lists: Migrated (boolean), MigrationStatus (multi-row text), and MigrationDate (DateTime).

I am using the WCF data services to upload the file to the new platform. The process is simple: (1) get certain number of items from source list; (2) check data to see if it meets standards for new platform; (3) if passes validation, upload to new SP2010 library, otherwise, update source library on WSS or MOSS to indicate why the data does not meet standards. Everything is working well with one huge caveat.

The content database's log files for the **source content database** are growing at an alarming rate. It appears that the log file is growing at a rate equal to the file size that is migrated. In other words, if I migrate 20 files that are 6MB each, the log will grow approximately 120MB. For such few files that is way TOO much. I have to migrate 45000 files.

No columns are indexed for this particular library. Versioning was on, but it has been turned off. With versioning off, the log files are still growing out of control during the migration. I am migrating approximately 50GB, and space is an issue.

So, my question....

What am I missing? By updating three fields, is a new version also being created without my knowledge, or is something else occurring?

The update code is below:

```
    public void SetMigrationStatus(string sourceList, int itemId, bool migratedSuccessfully, string migrationMessage, DateTime migrationDate) {
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        var updateElem = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Batch");
        var updateXmlText = new StringBuilder();           

        updateXmlText.Append("<Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'>");
        updateXmlText.Append(string.Format("<Field Name='ID'>{0}</Field>", itemId));
        updateXmlText.Append(string.Format("<Field Name='Migrated'>{0}</Field>", migratedSuccessfully));
        updateXmlText.Append(string.Format("<Field Name='MigrationStatus'>{0}</Field>", migrationMessage));

        if (migratedSuccessfully) {                
            updateXmlText.Append(string.Format("<Field Name='MigrationDate'>{0}</Field>",
                string.Format("{0} {1}",
                DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(),
                DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString())));
        }

        updateXmlText.Append("</Method>");

        updateElem.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");
        updateElem.SetAttribute("ListVersion", "1");
        updateElem.InnerXml = updateXmlText.ToString();

        var results = ListsServiceProxy.UpdateListItems(sourceList, updateElem);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you permitted to switch the SQL logging option on your source database to "simple" for the duration of the migration?  This should resolve the immediate issue.

(I guess it will depend on your backup strategy and SLAs.)

Comment: Argh! This resolves my problem, but I was hoping there was going to be a magic property that I may have been missing on the web service or on the document library. Thanks!

Comment: I'll up-vote your answer once I have enough reputation points.